# Create alphabetic index with letters repeating

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

I am running Debian 9. In Bash I can `echo {a..z}` for the alphabet, or `echo {a..z}{a..z}` to print letter combinations. However, I would like to generate an index with: `a b c d` etc. then `aa bb cc dd` etc. then `aaa bbb ccc ddd` etc. until it is `aaaaa bbbbb` (until `zzzzz`). How could this be done with brace expansion or another similar method? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
$ printf '%s ' {a..z}; echo
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z

$ printf '%s%s ' {a..z}{,}; echo
aa bb cc dd ee ff gg hh ... ss tt uu vv ww xx yy zz 

$ printf '%s%s%s ' {a..z}{,,}
aaa bbb ccc ddd eee ... ttt uuu vvv www xxx yyy zzz
```

Explained:
A brace expansion will  create one argument per each value delimited by the comma (and the leading string):

```
$ echo A{d,u,j}
Ad Au Aj
```

But, if the value is empty, it will just repeat the leading string:

```
$ echo A{,,}
A A A
```

If the leading string is itself a brace expansion, all its strings will be repeated:

```
$ echo {one,two}{,,}
one one one two two two
```

Then, the printf (and the trailing echo) are used to format the output:

```
$ printf '%s%s%s ' {one,two}{,,}; echo
oneoneone twotwotwo
```

With one letter values:

```
$ printf '%s%s%s ' {a..d}{,,}; echo
aaa bbb ccc ddd
```

Comment: This is a fairly clever answer, and I would probably have upvoted it *if you had explained how it works!*

Comment: @G-Man Better now?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't do this purely by having `bash` do some expansion magic. But you can always use

```
for c in {a..z}; do echo $c$c; done
for c in {a..z}; do echo $c$c$c; done
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option in Bash.

```
index=$(echo -n {a..z})
num=2
until ((num>5)); do
    for c in {a..z}; do
        case "$num" in
            2 ) index=$(echo -n "$index $c$c") ;;
            3 ) index=$(echo -n "$index $c$c$c") ;;
            4 ) index=$(echo -n "$index $c$c$c$c") ;;
            5 ) index=$(echo -n "$index $c$c$c$c$c") ;;
        esac
    done
((num++))
done
echo "$index"
```

1. Add the first set to the `index`.
2. Loop four times for the remaining four sets.
3. Run `for` loop for each letter.
4. The `case` statement in the `for` loop determines the number of instances each letter is added to the index.